# How to create non-executable jar with dependencies? (multi-module)

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml, multi-module

how are the pom settings for create a non-executable jar-with-dependencies? (multi-module)
I can‘t find anything working

Answer (score 1):

The [Maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html) can help. When configuring the plugin, you can control the contents of the manifest, thus making the jar non-executable. A sample configuration is provided [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ManifestResourceTransformer).